# Mochawesome reporter outputs incorrect json results while using Mocha's this.retries() api

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, mochawesome

Though I see an [open issue](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome/issues/125) about this , 
Wanted to check if we have a workaround, any suggestions appreciated ?  :

only while using `this.retries()`, I see the json results showing `null` for the elements `state` and `speed` the elements `pass` , `fail` as `false` and `err` is empty, also as the result of which the html report looks incorrect . Here's my test

```
describe(`Page Load checks `, async function ()  {

it('Page Check', async function () {
        this.retries(1); 
        presentationsPage = await navMenu.loadPresentationsPage();
        const result = await presentationsPage.isPresentationsPageLoadComplete();
        expect(result).to.equal(true, 'Expected : Presentation Page');
    }) ;
 } );
```

and the json results

```
{
              "title": "Page Check",
              "fullTitle": "Page Loads  Check",
              "timedOut": false,
              "duration": 32014,
              "state": null,
              "speed": null,
              "pass": false,
              "fail": false,
              "pending": false,
              "context": null,
              "code": "__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function...",
              "err": {},
              "uuid": "6971b4af-b327bda4ffa8",
              "parentUUID": "3345841e-6a5f-19fee98",
              "isHook": false,
              "skipped": true
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case any one lands into the same issue while using retries(), I switched to a reporting framework called [mocha-allure-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-allure-reporter) . I found this to be a great reporting framework.

Comment: and it is working fine? So many unresolved issues((( e.g. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-mocha/issues/55